# Bootstrap form action submit issue

Tags: html, forms

Iam new to bootstrap and I am trying to add an action="doform.php" to a form but I cant get it to work, where in this code should I add action?

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send invitation</button>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send invitation</button>
  </div>
```

I have tried the following but it doesnt do anything...

```
    <form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
<form id="back" action="doit1.php" method="post">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send invitation</button>
</form>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
<form id="back" action="doit1.php" method="post">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send invitation</button>
</form>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: You can't nest forms.

Comment: I have edited my post, I want two buttons inline to submit two different scripts

Comment: OK, but you still can't nest form elements.

Comment: What do you mean by 'can't get it to work'? As there isn't much else we can help with here. What are you trying to do, and what is it actually doing for you at the moment?

Comment: I have found a solution for my problem, bootstrap works a bit different... normally i would do two forms after eachother. now I have to use: <a class="btn btn-primary" href="../../" role="button">Continue</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `form` tag.

And don't forget the method. I assume you'll want to use POST

```
<form action="doAction.php" method="POST">
```

Oh, and you only need one submit button.

Comment: I have edited my post, I want two buttons inline to submit two different scripts

Comment: Are you including your form inputs?? That code as it is won't actually process any form information.

Comment: Its just an example, one if for the back button another to a different page. Normaly I can do inline in CSS but with bootstrap (Getbootstrap) is doesnt work. Maybe I am doing it wrong

Comment: Maybe because they're both submit, so they're both going to do the same thing.

Comment: I have found a solution for my problem, bootstrap works a bit different... normally i would do two forms after eachother. now I have to use: <a class="btn btn-primary" href="../../" role="button">Continue</a>